# Prove that $tr(A)^p = tr(A^p)\bmod p$ where $A$ is a square integer matrix and $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, trace

I'm looking for an elementary proof (one which does not use Galois theory). For the case $p = 3$, we have that $tr(A^3) = tr(A)^3 - 3e_1e_2 + 3e_3$ where the $e_i$ are coefficients of the characterstic polynomial of $A$, and are thus integers, so the result follows. I cannot see a way to generalize this for arbitrary $p$. Any help would be great!

Comment: It may help to consider the equivalent formulation
$$
\operatorname{tr}(n \,A^p - \operatorname{tr}(A)^p I) = 0
$$
where $n$ is the size of the matrix

Comment: I'm not sure whether my answer below is "elementary enough" (I'm still using the language of finite fields, but not any "deep theory" of). And [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) seems to be an overkill to apply here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A,B$ are *commuting* square matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of the same size, then
$$(A+B)^p=A^p+B^p$$
(the binomial formula is valid here, and $p\mid\binom{p}{k}$ for $0<k<p$). (The same holds for $A,B$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[\lambda]$, for the same reason.) It follows, for a matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, denoting by $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)$ its characteristic polynomial, that $(\lambda I-A)^p=\lambda^p I-A^p$ and therefore $\chi_{A^p}(\lambda^p)=\big(\chi_A(\lambda)\big)^p$. But $\big(f(x)\big)^p=f(x^p)$ for any polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ (this is usually proven by induction on the degree of $f$ using the same "binomial argument" as above, and the fact that $a^p=a$ for any $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$).

Thus actually we have $\chi_{A^p}(\lambda^p)=\chi_A(\lambda^p)$, i.e. just $\color{blue}{\chi_{A^p}\equiv\chi_A}$. As a corollary (comparing the coefficients), we get $\operatorname{tr}(A^p)=\operatorname{tr}(A)$, and we're done (again by $a^p=a$ for any $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$).

Comment: Could you explain why the line about the characteristic polynomials being equal?

Comment: I meant the equality between characteristic polynomials right after "and therefore ..."

Comment: Yes, I've edited this right before. We take $\det$ of the both sides of $(\lambda I-A)^p=\lambda^p I-A^p$.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that. It's clear now, thanks!

Comment: @reuns: for non-commuting $X,Y$, $(X+Y)^p=X^p+Y^p$ may fail to hold.

Comment: Oops you are right. So I agree that looking at $(A+\lambda I)^p$ is the only way then

Comment: I think this argument needs some additional explanation because we end up with an argument that when two polynomial expressions take identical values, the underlying polynomials must have identical coefficients.

This is true on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, but in $\mathbb F_p$ not. E.g. $X^p$ and $X$ take identical values on $\mathbb F_p$ but do not have identical coefficients.

Comment: @Chris: I don't think so. The equalities above (including the last paragraph) that involve polynomials in $\lambda$ are in $\mathbb{F}_p[\lambda]$. That is, these are equalities of *polynomials*, not just of the values taken at any fixed $\lambda$.